# Sending proactive messages to a channel in Teams

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams

So,

I searched far and wide, read everything I could find on the topic and I am still failing at this. I have managed to send proactive message to user, reply to a topic in team, etc. but I am unable to send a proactive message (create new post) in a team channel.

Is there an available example (I was unable to find any)? MS Docs for NodeJS seem to show an example of messaging each user in the team, but not the channel itself.

I explored the source code, and `channelData` is hardcoded to `null` inside `botFrameworkAdapter.js`, which only adds to the confusion.

So, basic code is:

```
const builder = require('botbuilder');
const adapter = new builder.BotFrameworkAdapter({
    appId: 'XXX',
    appPassword: 'YYY'
});

const conversation = {
  channelData: {
    //I have all this (saved from event when bot joined the Team)
  },
  ...
  // WHAT THIS OBJECT NEEDS TO BE TO SEND A SIMPLE "HELLO" TO A CHANNEL?
  // I have all the d
};

adapter.createConversation(conversation, async (turnContext) => {
  turnContext.sendActivity('HELLO'); //This may or may not be needed?
});
```

Has anyone done this with Node ? If so, can anyone show me a working example (with properly constructed `conversation` object)?

*** EDIT ***

As Hilton suggested in the answer below, I tried using `ConnectorClient` directly, but it returns resource unavailable (`/v3/conversations`)

Here is the code that I am using (it's literally only that, just trying to send demo message):

```
const path = require('path');
const { ConnectorClient, MicrosoftAppCredentials } = require('botframework-connector');

const ENV_FILE = path.join(__dirname, '.env');
require('dotenv').config({ path: ENV_FILE });

const serviceUrl = 'https://smba.trafficmanager.net/emea/';

async function sendToChannel() {
    MicrosoftAppCredentials.trustServiceUrl(serviceUrl);

    var credentials = new MicrosoftAppCredentials(process.env.MicrosoftAppId, process.env.MicrosoftAppPassword);
    var client = new ConnectorClient(credentials, { baseUri: serviceUrl });

    var conversationResponse = await client.conversations.createConversation({
        bot: {
            id: process.env.MicrosoftAppId,
            name: process.env.BotName
        },
        isGroup: true,
        conversationType: "channel",
        id: "19:XXX@thread.tacv2"
    });

    var acivityResponse = await client.conversations.sendToConversation(conversationResponse.id, {
        type: 'message',
        from: { id: process.env.MicrosoftAppId },
        text: 'This a message from Bot Connector Client (NodeJS)'
    });

}

sendToChannel();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please try this sample to [send proactive message in channel in Node](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/57.teams-conversation-bot/bots/teamsConversationBot.js). Please let us know if you face any issues.

Comment: @Gousia-MSFT Where does this send proactive message to channel? It is mostly replying to mentions, and only uses createConversation to message all members of the channel? As I stated in my question, I am trying to send a proactive message to channel, not reply to mention (I got that part working already).

Comment: The sample link i provided has different options: To reply to at mentions and to send a proactive message. Please look at [this](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/4f1ed84af5f0bc9ccbc9d05356005e3cb43486d7/samples/javascript_nodejs/57.teams-conversation-bot/bots/teamsConversationBot.js#L117). Here is the corresponding [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=javascript#tabpanel_CeZOj-G++Q-1_javascript) to send proactive messages.

Comment: @Gousia-MSFT Yes but it uses existing context from onMessage. I am trying to do createContext from data that I have stored, and I am unable to do so apparently.

Comment: You don't seem to have a conversation reference. Messages can't be sent by bots without the user first interacting with the bot giving you a conversation reference. Installing the application into teams will give you this initial reference. Try and follow this example github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/…

Comment: @Gousia-MSFT it's all bells and whistles like that, I know that and that part works. However, the real issue here is storing the conversation reference in the database and continuing it at a later time (in case the bot restarts, or similar). That's why I am trying to use createConversation, but failing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, so, this is how I made it work. I am posting it here for future reference.

***DISCLAIMER***: I still have no idea how to use it with `botbuilder` as was asked in my initial question, and this answer is going to use `ConnectorClient`, which is acceptable (for me, at least). Based on Hilton's directions and a GitHub issue that I saw earlier ( https://github.com/OfficeDev/BotBuilder-MicrosoftTeams/issues/162#issuecomment-434978847 ), I made it work finally. MS Documentation is not that helpful, since they always use `context` variable which is available when your Bot is responding to a message or activity, and they keep a record of these contexts internally while the Bot is running. However, if your Bot is restarted for some reason or you want to store your data in your database to be used later, this is the way to go.

So, the code (NodeJS):

```
const path = require('path');
const { ConnectorClient, MicrosoftAppCredentials } = require('botframework-connector');

const ENV_FILE = path.join(__dirname, '.env');
require('dotenv').config({ path: ENV_FILE });

const serviceUrl = 'https://smba.trafficmanager.net/emea/';

async function sendToChannel() {
    MicrosoftAppCredentials.trustServiceUrl(serviceUrl);

    var credentials = new MicrosoftAppCredentials(process.env.MicrosoftAppId, process.env.MicrosoftAppPassword);
    var client = new ConnectorClient(credentials, { baseUri: serviceUrl });

    var conversationResponse = await client.conversations.createConversation({
        bot: {
            id: process.env.MicrosoftAppId,
            name: process.env.BotName
        },
        isGroup: true,
        conversationType: "channel",
        channelData: {
            channel: { id: "19:XXX@thread.tacv2" }
        },
        activity: {
            type: 'message',
            text: 'This a message from Bot Connector Client (NodeJS)'
        }
    });

}

sendToChannel();
```

***NOTE***: As Hilton pointed out, `serviceUrl` also needs to be loaded from your database, along with the channel id. It is available inside the activity which you receive initially when your Bot is added to team / channel / group along with `channelId` which you will also need, and you need to store those for future reference (do not hardcode them like in the example).

So, there is no separate `createConversation` and `sendActivity`, it's all in one call.

Thanks Hilton for your time, and a *blurred image of my hand*  to MS Docs :)

Hope this helps someone else

Comment: Hi dkasipovic, So to send Notification, do we need to fetch ServiceUrl from DB? as I was thinking it is static and hardcoded in code.

Comment: @Chekrii You should always store and use serviceUrl that you receive first time you install the bot or add it to a channel / group. In general, storing hardcoded strings in your apps is rarely a good idea.

Comment: @dkasipovic this works. though for me it always posts in the general channel. Actually for some reasons i always get the same channel id instead of newly created channel id. do u know why?'

Comment: I have not read a single post or thread about MS Teams Bot development that doesn't express deep pain and frustration

Answer (score 2):

(I'm replacing my previous answer as I think this fits the situation much better).

I've looked more into this and done a Fiddler trace to get you a more complete answer. I'm not a Node guy, so I'm not sure this will translate *100%*, but let's see.

Basically, you're wanting to send to the following endpoint:
https://smba.trafficmanager.net/emea/v3/conversations/19:[RestOfYourChannelId]/activities

and you'll be posting a message like the following:

```
{
  "type": "message",
  "from": {
    "id": "28:[rest of bot user id]",
    "name": "[bot name]"
  },
  "conversation": {
    "isGroup": true,
    "conversationType": "channel",
    "id": "19:[RestOfYourChannelId]"
  },
  "text": "Test Message"
}
```

However, to post to that endpoint, you need to authenticate to it properly. It's possible to do that, and communicate with the endpoint directly, but it's actually easier to just use the built-in mechanisms. This means getting and storing the conversationreference when the bot is first installed to the channel. [This file](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/16.proactive-messages/bots/proactiveBot.js) shows how to do that (see how it gets and stores the conversationReference in the `this.onConversationUpdate` function). In that same sample, in a different file, it shows how to use that conversation reference to actually send the pro-active message - see [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/16.proactive-messages/index.js#L71), where it uses `adapter.continueConversation`.

One of the Microsoft bot team members also shows this in similar detail over [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/bot-docs/issues/1434#issuecomment-558720710). He also adds `MicrosoftAppCredentials.trustServiceUrl(ref.serviceUrl);` which can be necessary under certain circumstances (if you're having security issues, give that a try).

That -should- cover what you need, so give it a go, and let me know if you're still having difficulties.

Comment: Thank you for your insight, those things I have definitely tried. I even managed to make it work with `continueConversation` which sends a reply to a post, so I definitely have good data, I am just stumped on how to use it with `createActivity` as it just keeps returning error 400 with "very helpful" message of `Invalid json`

Comment: When I've had that, it's actually usually been correct and I've made a silly mistake, like a missing comma at the end of a line. Is that possible here?

Comment: No, not really because I am using 'restify' to accept JSON so all JSON passed to 'createConversation' is definitely valid

Comment: then perhaps it's the payload itself. Are you able to send a sample of that?

Comment: Well yeah, it's definitely the payload, that's what am I asking. What the payload should be?

Comment: @dkasipovic did you see my updated answer? Does it help?

Comment: I will give it a spin soon, and let you know. I know how to store reference, but the issue is that if for some reason bot is restarted, you loose references and need to wait for someone to do something again, or re-add the bot. That's why I need to use data stored in database.

Comment: Nope, it says Invalid JSON, though I read somewhere online that it definitely needs to include `channelData` when using NodeJS so I suspect that your object might be fine when using manual authentication and sending. If you can guide me on how to do that, that might work too.

Comment: somehow I missed these notificiations, only seeing them now. Yes, you should for sure store in a database - the sample was just showing how to get them

Comment: Regarding the manual authentication, basically I'm just creating an instance of ConnectorClient from  the Microsoft.Bot.Connector namespace in C#. It seems like it would map to this: https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/tree/master/libraries/botframework-connector. Then under createConversation you specify what's needed ("channel" as the type, and the conversationId). I haven't done it in node though, so not -100%- sure what the code would look like, but that seems to be the equivalent of what I'm using in C#

Comment: hm yeah, that might work, I'll check it out later and let you know

Comment: ok great. Somehow it doesn't notify me of updates on this thread, so I'll try keep an eye on it as best as possible.

Comment: I'm not sure if you need "createConversation" per se, there might be a "continueConversation" or similar - look into that, but otherwise it looks pretty good. I think the error you're getting now is that you're not setting the base url to use (it's per endpoint, so you need to set it for "Teams" in this case). Basically, you need to use the "serviceUrl" from your conversation context, when you create your ConnectorClient. See here: https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/2d5a230d1e8880719348cf9c9a5b860685d35480/libraries/botbuilder/src/botFrameworkAdapter.ts#L1051

Comment: any luck with this?

Comment: Yes, I added the url then it was permission denied, so then I added `trustServiceUrl` and now we're getting somewhere. Currently I am getting `Error: Incorrect conversation creation parameters` which probably means that the problem is somewhere in JSON. I edited my question to include the latest code

Comment: ok great! Yeah, I forgot to mention about TrustServiceUrl. Also, be aware that the serviceUrl itself you need to get from the conversation details, as it will change based on tenant etc. (I see you're hard-coding it, which is fine for testing, but pointing it out for future). Right now, I think your problem is `id: process.env.MicrosoftAppId` - while this is -derived from- your app Id, it needs to start with "28:", so it's `"28:" + process.env.MicrosoftAppId`

Comment: I think you also shouldn't need `from: { id: process.env.MicrosoftAppId },` on your "acivityResponse", but start with the id for the conversation, as per my previous comment

Comment: I dont think thats the issue but will try right away. Inthink that the 28: goes to the "from" parameter in sendToConversation, not in createConversation. Will try right away though

Comment: Nope, tried with the 28: + id part and it's still the same error

Comment: I did it! I'll update in a moment. Points are yours because you steered me in the right direction :) Thanks!

Comment: you got it working?? that's great! Waiting to see what it was in the end...

Comment: Please check out my edit. I am accepting your answer as it is what made me look in the right direction. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Actually, as per StackExchange guidelines I posted my solution as an answer but I still awarded you the bounty. Thanks again!